# Force compile error if method has blocking calls in Dot Net 4

Tags: c#, .net

This question is for the .NET Framework 4

Is anyone aware of a way to force the compiler to generate an error when a given instance method makes any calls that block the thread. I am working in a body of code and would like a mechanical way to make sure that nothing in the execution chain will block the thread.

I have been trying to find a property I can add to a method declaration but have not been able to find anything.

When I use the word block I didn't mean just any code that may hang. Specifically some of the Microsoft api calls like SMTP.Send() and NetworkStream.Read() will stop execution until a specific event is reached.

Comment: What do you mean by calls that block the thread? All calls block the thread for the duration of their execution.

Comment: You can add your own thread manager and check the `ThreadState` attribute of the thread you are monitoring.

Comment: Even if you could define "block the thread", this would require the compiler to know what you mean by that, and the compiler doesn't know these sorts of things.

Comment: You could try something with annotations and FxCop: mark "good" methods as `[Nonblocking]` and verify that any function with that annotation only calls other functions that also have it.

Comment: Some specific calls like SMTP.Send() or NetworkStream.Read() will block until an event occurs. I was under the impression that maybe under the covers there was some way to detect this state, but I have no idea how the blocking is performed.

I understand that all code "blocks" until its done executing, but I was using the term block me known api calls that wait until an event is trigger. I should clear this up in my question.

Comment: The FxCop is something I would like to look into, but its way beyond the scope of me just trying to verify that my thread of code doesn't hit any Microsoft api code that will hang waiting for an event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use FxCop SDK to write your own code analysis rule , set the message level to Error so that whenever the rule is violated it will show up as "compile error" , take a look at this blog for more information [Custom Code Analysis Rules](http://blog.tatham.oddie.com.au/2010/01/06/custom-code-analysis-rules-in-vs2010-and-how-to-make-them-run-in-fxcop-and-vs2008-too/)

Comment: something like this is what I was hoping was already implemented in some form. If the MSDN doc mentions stuff blocks maybe there was some mechanism for it.

That said I can't find anything myself. I feel the Custom Code Analysis Rules capture the spirit of my question.

Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

Joshua i'm sorry but i dont think you understand the concept of a blocking call... See all calls are blocking, the only difference is that some blocks last longer than others! We usually say that a call is a "non-blocking call" when the "long blocking" part occurs in a different thread...

A more direct answer is: No, the compiler is not aware that a call will cause blocking so he can't figure it out!